# MySQL 5.7 intermittent max connections errors

Tags: mysql, connection, max

I’m having a problem with MySQL 5.7 with « too many connections » causing services crashes. The max_connections system variable is set at 1000 and on average there are +/- 250 sessions/thread, so it’s odd that the max connections are being reached. The issue appears mostly at night between 10 and 11 pm at certain weeknights.

The machine is a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise Server with 32 Gb RAM and Dual Xeon CPUs. Here's some more environmental information:

```
    Variable            |   Max Connection Memory
-------------------------------------------------
join_buffer_size        |       250.00 MB
read_buffer_size        |       62.50 MB
read_rnd_buffer_size    |       250.00 MB
sort_buffer_size        |       250.00 MB
max_connections = 1000  |       812.50 MB

Timeouts                    |   VALUE
-------------------------------------------
connect_timeout             |   10
delayed_insert_timeout      |   300
have_statement_timeout      |   YES
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout |   1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    |   50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  |   OFF
interactive_timeout         |   28800
lock_wait_timeout           |   31536000
net_read_timeout            |   30
net_write_timeout           |   60
rpl_stop_slave_timeout      |   31536000
slave_net_timeout           |   60
wait_timeout                |   28800
-------------------------------------------
max_allowed_packet          | 33554432
slave_max_allowed_packet    | 1073741824
```

### Sample log file

```
Aborted connection 27933 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'eifprdrds01.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 26736 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'eifprdrds01.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 27200 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'eifprdrds01.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 27356 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'eifprdrds01.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 29119 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'pc286.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 16274 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'pc828.domain.com' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 24916 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'pc830.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 19357 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'pc830.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
Aborted connection 19343 to db: 'wms_mysql' user: 'mysql' host: 'pc830.domain.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I'm somewhat at a loss as to what's happening.  Any advice would be very useful!

Comment: This probably better fits on http://dba.stackexchange.com, as it is not (directly) about programming, but administration (although it might turn out to be a coding problem). Up until then, you should check if your system does something specific between 10-11pm. Although an odd time, I'd specifically check for a backup process (either for your mysql server or for your windows server) that might make processes wait or slow down (so they might accumulate and reach your limit).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

```
join_buffer_size=256K  # from 250M to reduce RAM request
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 62.50M to reduce RAM request
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 250M to reduce RAM request
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 250M to reduce RAM request
```

the first 4 are RAM requests PER connection and your present config is 100X default for most of them and causing the server to EXCEED AVAILABLE RAM. You may detect this in your error log of MySQL.

For additional suggestions, view my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch via Skype, please.